# Adding a string to a list adds each character separately

Tags: python, string, list, augmented-assignment

```
function = input('Enter function')
a = input('do you want to enter another function')
b = [function]
if a.lower() == 'yes':
    while True:
        function1 = input('Next Function')
        b += function1
        if function1 == 'quit':
            break

print(b)
```

in this code if I input in function1: y = 9x + 1; it will put the values in the array, but in the format: `'y', ' ', '9x', ' ', '+', ' ', '1'`.
how do save the input as `y = 9x + 1'?`
Also when I write quit, it prints the array, but the final value is `q','u','i','t'`.
How do I eliminate those values?

Comment: b.append(function1) instead of b+=

Comment: Change `b += function1` to `b += [function1]`

Comment: thank you, it works, and I managed to remove 'quit' from the array

Comment: You have defined `b` not correctly,that's why it comes to have wrong answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first request you can simply use `.append()` on `b` to append the element to the list `b`.

**Code solving first issue:**

```
b.append(function1)
```

For your second request you could simply check if quit was typed before appending element to `b`

**Code solving second issue:**

```
while True:
    function1 = input('Next Function: ')
    if function1 == 'quit':
        break
    b.append(function1)
```

**Final Code:**

```
function = input('Enter function: ')
a = input('Do you want to enter another function: ')
b = [function]
if a.lower() == 'yes':
    while True:
        function1 = input('Next Function: ')
        if function1 == 'quit':
            break
        b.append(function1)


print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to save "quit" as it is, you just need to change `b += function1` with `b.append(function1)`.

The corrected code is the following:

```
function = input('Enter function')
a = input('do you want to enter another function')
b = [function]
if a.lower() == 'yes':
    while True:
        function1 = input('Next Function')
        b.append(function1)
        if function1 == 'quit':
            break

print(b)
```

In case you don't want the 'quit' string at all in the list, you can change the code as follows:

```
function = input('Enter function')
    a = input('do you want to enter another function')
    b = [function]
    if a.lower() == 'yes':
        while True:
            function1 = input('Next Function')
            if function1 == 'quit':
                break
            else:
                b.append(function1)

    print(b)
```

Additionally, this code is already saving the input `y = 9x + 1` as it is (it does not save it as `'y', ' ', '9x', ' ', '+', ' ', '1'`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding /n at the end of the string

```
function = input('Enter function\n')
a = input('do you want to enter another function\n')
b = [function]
if a.lower() == 'yes':
    while True:
        function1 = input('Next Function\n')
        b.append(function1)
        if function1 == 'quit':
            break

print(b[:-1])
```

u should use append. and see here that the last element u are adding to the answer was the value the user entered "quit" you can either remove it from the list or just don't print the last item of the list as I did in my example or don't even put it in there in the first place.

Comment: how about simply moving  `b.append(function1)`  _after_  `if function1 == 'quit': break` - won't be added in that case

Comment: @PatrickArtner well yeah of course it is a good option. as you can see from all the answers this post got in seconds, many different ways can be considered.